# How to Detect single and Double click in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've written the following code:

```
void OnMouseUpAsButton()
    {
        if (Type == 0) {            
            if (click && Time.time <= (clickTime + clickDelta))
            {
                Debug.Log("Double");
                Destroy(sp);
                click = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("one");
                click = true;
                clickTime = Time.time;
                Destroy(sp);
            }
        }else if (Type == -1)
        {            
                Destroy(sp);                                 
        }

    }
```

It detects double-click But has a problem!

in Both, objects will be removed

When you first click happens, Object is deleted And the second click is not recognized!

I want for Android

please help me. thanks

Answer (score 2):

The following class can be used in Editor or device.

```
public class InputController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public event Action OnSingleTap;
    public event Action OnDoubleTap;
    [Tooltip("Defines the maximum time between two taps to make it double tap")]
    [SerializeField]private float tapThreshold = 0.25f;
    private Action updateDelegate;
    private float tapTimer = 0.0f;
    private bool tap = false;

    private void Awake()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR || UNITY_STANDALONE
        updateDelegate = UpdateEditor;
#elif UNITY_IOS || UNITY_ANDROID
        updateDelegate = UpdateMobile;
#endif
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        if(updateDelegate != null){ updateDelegate();}
    }
    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        OnSingleTap = null;
        OnDoubleTap = null;
    }
#if UNITY_EDITOR || UNITY_STANDALONE
    private void UpdateEditor()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            if (Time.time < this.tapTimer + this.tapThreshold)
            {
                if(OnDoubleTap != null){ OnDoubleTap(); }
                this.tap = false;
                return;
            }
            this.tap = true;
            this.tapTimer = Time.time;
        }
        if (this.tap == true && Time.time>this.tapTimer + this.tapThreshold)
        {
             this.tap = false;
             if(OnSingleTap != null){ OnSingleTap();}
    }
    }
#elif UNITY_IOS || UNITY_ANDROID
    private void UpdateMobile ()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++)
        {
            if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                if(Input.GetTouch(i).tapCount == 2)
                {
                    if(OnDoubleTap != null){ OnDoubleTap();}
                }
                if(Input.GetTouch(i).tapCount == 1)
                {
                    if(OnSingleTap != null) { OnSingleTap(); }
                }
            }
        }
    }
#endif
}
```

Comment: Unless you are the original author of this script please provide proper attribution to the [original source](https://unitygem.wordpress.com/single-double-tap/). Unitygems falls under [creative commons](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/)  . Also if you're going to change `OnSingleTap` to `OnSingleTapHandler` and `OnDoubleTap` to `OnDoubleTapHandler` it should be consistent throughout the entire script.

Comment: I am the original author of this post. Not sure how I can prove it but yes I am.

Comment: Ok I changed the original code so it is no longer the same :).

Answer (score 1):

You're telling it to destroy the object in both halves of your if-statement (re-read your inner `else` block). You would need to set up your update method or coroutine to process a single click after the Double Click timer has been reached.

Simple sample below:

```
void OnMouseUpAsButton()
{
    if(!clicked)
    {
        clicked = true;
        return;
    }

    if(Time.time <= (clickTime + clickDelta))
    {
        //Double Click occured
        clicked = false;
    }
}

void Update()
{
    if(clicked)
    {
       if(Time.time >= (clickTime + clickDelta))
       {
           //Handle single click
           clicked = false;
       }
    }
}
```

Note this is just to demonstrate a simple way to handle this using most of what you provided.

You can also find additional information at this question:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/331545/double-click-mouse-detection-.html